# How to incorporate unicode character in a CASE statement in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, case, ssms, special-characters, unicode-escapes

I have a column of type 'nvarchar' where some of the values have special characters. What I want to do is, if a value starts with a special character, then perform a function to remove that character, else return the value as is. The sample data is as follows:

| ID | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 999.09999.09 |
| 2 | 339.58339.58 |
| 3 | 2141.12055.72357.6 |
| 4 | 519.32519.32 |
| 5 | 661.84661.84 |
| 6 | 843.59843.59 |

I tried to use the 'STUFF' function to replace a special character whenever a value starts with it. i-e,

```
SELECT  ID,
        STUFF (Amount, 1, 1, '') AS Test,
FROM        table
```

I works for individual value.

But when I apply this to the whole column using CASE statement (since all values don't start with a special character), then I fail to incorporate the special character in LIKE operator. I tried the following query:

```
SELECT  ID,
        CASE
            WHEN Amount LIKE N'%'
            THEN (STUFF (Amount, 1, 1, ''))
            ELSE Amount
        END AS Test,
        
FROM        table
```

**Results Expected:**

| ID | Amount | Test |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 999.09999.09 | 999.09999.09 |
| 2 | 339.58339.58 | 339.58339.58 |
| 3 | 2141.12055.72357.6 | 2141.12055.72357.6 |
| 4 | 519.32519.32 | 519.32519.32 |
| 5 | 661.84661.84 | 661.84661.84 |
| 6 | 843.59843.59 | 843.59843.59 |

The data looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Stu. Can you help with the problem?

Comment: "populated with numeric values", no they seem to be non-numeric values.  What datatype does the column `Amount` have ?

Comment: It is NVARCHAR.

Comment: Can you reproduce your error in a controlled environment as this one? https://dbfiddle.uk/ER_9PaV-

Comment: What exactly *are* these special characters? They show as `U+F8FC`/`U+F8FD` on my screen now, but those are private use codepoints, not regular characters. See what `CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), Amount)` gives you. If the data is accurate they can be replaced with, e.g. `REPLACE(REPLACE(Amount, NCHAR(0xf8fc) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2, ' '), NCHAR(0xf8fd) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2, ' ')` (a binary collation is not strictly required for these characters, but comes in handy in general for whitespace-like characters that wouldn't otherwise match anything).

Comment: @Jeroen: It's kind of a dot.   https://paste.pics/5285ef35be3c7f86ced37c40f0fb6bf6

Comment: It's not a dot; that's just how it happens to render on your machine. Mine has a Unicode fallback font that shows the hex value of the character in question. There are "true" dot characters in Unicode, but these aren't it. Hence why I asked about conversion to `VARBINARY`, as it will show the actual code points.

Comment: You appear to have the wrong match character in your `LIKE` condition. Your current `LIKE` is looking for a character at the start that actually appears in teh middle of your sample data.  If you change it to `LIKE N'%', you should get your desired results.  See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/T3YP-cwQ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your data is either numerics or special characters you could just check for it *not* being a number:

```
case when Amount not like N'[0-9]%' then (Stuff (Amount, 1, 1, '')) else Amount end as Test
```

Comment: How would I return the first part in case of multi part value delimited by a special character?
e.g. If I want to return 2141.1 from 2141.12055.72357.6

Answer (score 0):

Loosing the *other* characters can be done like this:

```sql
WITH nrs as (
    SELECT 1 as x 
    union all
    select x+1 from nrs where x<25
  ),
cte as 
        (select Amount,substring(Amount,1,1) as a from mytable
         union all
         select Amount,substring(Amount,x+1,1) as a
         from mytable
         cross apply nrs x)
select mytable.Amount, string_agg(a,'') as NewNumber
from mytable
inner join cte on cte.Amount = mytable.Amount and a<>''
where a between '0'and '9' or a='.' or a=','
group by mytable.Amount;
```

output:

| Amount | NewNumber |
| --- | --- |
| ?339.58?339.58 | 339.58339.58 |
| ?519.32?519.32 | 29.312539.15 |
| ?661.84?661.84 | 66.186468.14 |
| ?843.59?843.59 | 93.549853.48 |
| ?999.09?999.09 | 9990.99990.9 |
| 2141.1?2055.72?357.6 | 27357.6.55021.1421 |

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/SRYbfY-C)

NOTE: `NewNumber` is still not numeric! It just contains numbers and/or a '.' and/or a ','.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TRIM - for SQL Server 2019 and below, TRIM removes the leading and trailing characters.  For SQL Server 2022 you can specify leading/trailing/both:

Sample Data:

```
Declare @testData Table (ID int, Amount nvarchar(50));
 Insert Into @testData (ID, Amount)
 Values (1, N'999.09999.09')
      , (2, N'339.58339.58')
      , (3, N'2141.12055.72357.6')
      , (4, N'519.32519.32')
      , (5, N'661.84661.84')
      , (6, N'843.59843.59');
```

SQL Server 2017:

```
 Select *
      , Test = trim(N'' From td.Amount)
   From @testData td;
```

SQL Server 2022:

```
 Select *
      , Test = trim(leading N'' From td.Amount)
   From @testData td;
```